# Update file name automatically within VBA

Tags: excel

I have a  excel file that is referenced in my macro that is named inventory report " today's date " ex. ( Inventroy report 11_01_2017) I was trying to find a way for VBA to always reference the file with the current date in its name

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the current file name, plus the current date, you can do:

```
Sub t()
Dim fileName As String, curDate As String
curDate = Date
fileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
fileName = Left(fileName, InStr(fileName, ".") - 1)
fileName = fileName & " " & curDate
Debug.Print fileName
End Sub
```

If you need date with `_` instead of `/` you can add:

```
curDate = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(date, "/", "_")
```